# Как правильно спроектировать компонент на подгрузку динамического контента (формы)

Tags: архитектура, angular5

Вопрос чисто теоретический, на архитектуру. Каким образом реализовать динамическое отображение форм, каким путем лучше всего пойти?

Пример:

1. Категория - *автомобиль*. Форма с полями - марка, пробег, год выпуска...
2. Категория - *лодка*. Форма с полями - грузоподъемность, длина,...
3. Категория - *самолет*. Форма с полями - к-во пассажиров, макс. высота...

маршрут - **transports/:id/details** , по которому открывается компонент TransportDetailsComponent.

С учетом того, что категорий может быть много. Как выводить компоненты(формы) под каждую категорию с минимальным написанием кода. На данный момент, склоняюсь в сторону **ng-template** с проверками на каждый. Буду очень благодарен за советы...

Comment: это не относится к архитектуре, названия полей должны приходить с сервера, вот и рендерить то что пришло

Comment: Если допустить, что эти данные должны по разному отображаться, для разных категорий. Возможно я привел глупый пример. Но в TransportDetailsComponent должен подтянуться еще компонент (ShipComponent) / (CarComponent)/ ...

Comment: Более точный пример - Аукцион, со своими данными. В который потом нужно добавлять лоты, в зависимости от рубрики аукциона

Comment: если категорий много и невозможно вынести определенную логику на бек, то вынесите логику в код (не в шаблон), используйте динамические компоненты (`ComponentFactoryResolver + ViewContainerRef`), которые будут создаваться на лету в зависимости от выбранной категории. Для обработки бизнес логики вы можете создать разные сервисы основанные на паттерне стратегия, для `ShipComponent - ShipStrategy`, `CarComponent - CarStrategy`, это в случае если их бизнес логика не пересекается

Comment: Вот это уже то, что я искал, спасибо!